# how to update a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have some code that stores data in a dictionary and than the dictionary is stored in a JSON file:

```
def store_data(user_inp):

list_of_letters = list(user_inp)
list_of_colons = []
nested_dict = {}

for letter in list_of_letters:
    if letter == ':':
        list_of_colons.append(letter)

jf = json.dumps(storage)
with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(jf)

if len(list_of_colons) == 2:
    str1 = ''.join(list_of_letters)
    list2 = str1.split(':')
    main_key = list2[0]
    nested_key = list2[1]
    value = list2[2]
    if main_key not in storage:
        storage[main_key] = nested_dict
        nested_dict[nested_key] = value
        print(storage, '\n', 'successfully saved!')
        jf = json.dumps(storage)
        with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(jf)

    elif main_key in storage:
        if nested_key in storage[main_key]:
            print('this item is already saved: \n', storage)
        else:
            storage[main_key][nested_key] = value
            print(storage, '\n', 'successfully saved!')
            jf = json.dumps(storage)
            with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
                f.write(jf)
```

The problem is that every time I rerun the program and enter new data, the data in the JSON file is replaced by the data entered the last time I ran the program. For example: If I want to store this string: gmail:pass:1234. What my function does is this:
creates a dictionary with the user input and stores it in the JSON file:

```
{'gmail': {'pass': 1234}}
```

As long I don't close the program, the data I enter keeps adding to the JSON object. But if I close the program, run it again, and enter new data, the data I stored before is replaced by  the data I entered last.

So what I want is that every time I enter a new piece of data to the dictionary, it will add it to the object stored in the JSON file. So if I run the program again and enter this input, gmail:pass2:2343, this is how it should be stored:

```
{'gmail': {'pass': '1234', 'pass2': '2343'}}
```

And if I enter this, zoom:id:1234567, I want it to add this to the object inside the JSON file, like so:

```
{'gmail': {'pass': '1234', 'pass2': '2343'} 'zoom': {'id': '1234567'}}
```

I really don't know how to fix this, I already researched but I can't find the solution to my specific case.

Hope you understand what I mean. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
def update_with_item(old, new_item):
    changed = True
    top_key, nested_key, value = new_item
    if top_key in old:
        if nested_key in old[top_key]:
            changed = False
            print("This item is already saved: \n", storage)
        else:
            old[top_key][nested_key] = value
    else:
        old[top_key] = {nested_key: value}
    return old, changed


def main():
    stored = json.load(open('myStorage.json'))
    old, changed = update_with_item(stored, list2)
    if changed:
        jf = json.dumps(old)
        with open('myStorage.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(jf)
        print(storage, '\n', 'successfully saved!')
```

I'm also not sure how you looping over the code in main, or where the list2 variable is coming from. The main function here will need to be updated to how you are looping over creating the new values etc.

The update_with_item function should resolve the issue you are having with updating the dictionary though.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help!  I edited my question so now you can see the whole function. In the main function you wrote, list2 is undefined if I implement it in my code. list2 in my function is basically a temporary variable since it's only splitting the string. I can understand your function but it doesn't seem to do anything in my code. Do I need to replace it with something? Maybe now that I show my whole function you can understand my problem better.

Comment: @telemaster if this helped I would apreciate if you could mark this as the resolution to the question, helps me out :)